# Throwing uncatchable ExecutionEngineException

Tags: code-golf, c#

The shortest C# code that generates an uncatchable ExecutionEngineException wins. You are not allowed to call FailFast directly or indirectly.

Comment: Welcome to programming puzzles and codegolf. There's a couple of reasons why you challenge may be unpopular: 1.If you search, you'll see we've had similar challenges before; 2. Language-specific challenges are frowned upon as they limit participation. I suggest you stick around, answer a few challenges and feel free to post the next one at    http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active

Answer (score 6):

## C# - 73

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_=>{throw new ExecutionEngineException();});
```

Generates an `ExecutionEngineException` inside of a thread, so it can't be caught.

<sub>User [CSharpie](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/22846/) helped me shorten `delegate` to `_=>`.</sub>

Comment: You should be able to replace delegate with a lambda _=> to make it even shorter.

Comment: @CSharpie First time golfing in C#. Thanks for the tip!